# merge some elements into one in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, excel

I hava a list just like

```
list = {{a1},
        {a2},   
        {a31,a32,a33}, 
        {a41,a42}}
```

I want to save it to excel, but it will in different column like

[image]

Now I want they are all in the same column, maybe separate by comma or other mark symbol.

Comment: You could use `Flatten[list]` to get rid of all sub lists.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of the desired output? That would make it much more clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `Row` command to convert a list into comma separate values.  However, we must convert the row into a string before we export.  If we do this

```
Export["tmp1.xls",
  ToString[Row[#,","]]&  /@  list
]
```

then we get an Excel file with one column that contains only text data.  Even if we set `a1=3.14` in MMA, it will be text in Excel.

If our row contains only one value we do not need the `Row` command or the `ToString` command.  So, we could do this

```
Export["tmp2.xls",
  If[Length[#] > 1,
    ToString[Row[#, ","]],
    First[#]] & /@ list
 ]
```

The second version will export rows that contain single numbers as numbers.

So far we have only considered a list of lists.  What if we want to export this:  `list3 = { 3.14, {1, 4, 9} };` ?  We would want the number 3.14 to appear in Excel, along the text "1, 4, 9".  Here is how we could do it.

```
list3 = {3.14, {1, 4, 9}};
Export["tmp3.xls",
 Which[
   Head[#] === List,
    If[Length[#] > 1,
     ToString[Row[#, ","]],
     First[#]],
   True, #] & /@ list3
 ]
```

This code checks to see if the element is a list.  If it is a list, and its length is greater than 1, we need to convert it to a row.  Otherwise, we do not change the element.